# SQL Server 2008, not enough disk space

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm executing sql query on my database. I have SQL Server 2008 installed on my D harddrive which has 55 GB free space.

I have also C drive which has sth like 150 MB free (right now).

While executing that query on quite a big table (16 GB) I have an error:

> An error occurred while executing
>   batch. Error message is: Not enough
>   disk space.

I would like to know if there is any possibility that I can make SQL Server to use D drive instead of C

Or maybe there is any other problem with what I'm doing ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

This is likely a logging issue.  You can move the log file to a different drive and use a lower level logging.

Comment: Log file is set to be written on D drive, executing this query takes a lot of free space on my C drive dont even know which file is beeing modified, 

what else can I do ?

Comment: What about the TEMPDBs?

Comment: there are also stored on D drive according to options which are set :/

Comment: Wild Guess: Try setting the TEMP and TMP system variables to a directory on the D drive.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be the TEMPDB, one of SQL Server's System databases. It will have been created in the default database location by the installer.

[This article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3379901/Moving-the-Tempdb-and-Master-Database-in-SQL-Server.htm) talks about moving the tempdb.

Equally you could add additional (expandable) files on D: to the tempdb database's primary filegroup, then set the default ones to fixed size (and eventually flush, then remove them).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the query using a client application on the SQL server, like SSMS? If so, it could be, probably is, using the C drive to store the output for display, especially if you're running the output to a grid. Try running the query using the SQLCMD command line.